# 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable while calculating the average of 3 lists

Tags: python, numpy

Here's part of my code that gives me the Typeerror:

```
basis_result = [np.average([1,2,4]),np.average([2,5]),np.average([2,5,4,3])]
aa = [i*d+j*b+k*c+a for i,j,k in zip(*basis_result)]
```

where a,b,c,d are some random numbers. It returns `'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`. Is that because I used `np.average` for each element in `basis_result`? The actual lists being averaged are much longer, so I wonder how can I fix this issue? Thanks for the help!

**Update**: I want to figure out if there's a faster way I can calculate `np.average([1,2,4])*a+np.average([2,5])*b+np.average([2,5,4,3])*c+d`, where a,b,c,d are random numbers.

Comment: average returns a float, not an iterable. What would be the expected output? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo  Thanks! I wonder if there's a faster way I can calculate `np.average([1,2,4])*a+np.average([2,5])*b+np.average([2,5,4,3])*c+d`, where a,b,c,d are random numbers.

Comment: Faster than simply doing: `np.average([1,2,4])*a+np.average([2,5])*b+np.average([2,5,4,3])*c+d`?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo yeah... But I just realized probably this works fine.

Comment: As part of your debugging did you look at `basis_result`?

Comment: @hpaulj No I didn't.